# Problem on my texture

Tags: modeling

Blender 2.8 version. I have a grey line on the Earth. Why and how can I remove it? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello, I guess it depends on how your UV is laying over the image in the UV Editor?

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org) Please don't post photos of your monitor, these are hard to diagnose because we can't tell if we are looking at a physical issue like reflection or smudge, a hardware issue like a malfunctioning display, a software level issue, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.